# ¿Cómo puedo ajustar la salida de un texto en un JfxDialog?

Tags: javafx, diálogo

Tengo un dialogo en Jfoenix que muestra un texto tecleado por el usuario, pero si el texto es muy largo el dialogo adquiere un ancho superior a la ventana. Ya intenté limitar el ancho del stackpane y no supone diferencia. Supongo que una solución sería añadir un textarea al diálogo para mostrar el texto o añadir saltos de linea automáticos a la variable que contiene el texto tecleado. He buscado la solución en internet hasta ahora sin éxito ¿Es posible realizar esto?

```
    String content = user_typed_text.getText();
    JFXDialogLayout Typed_text = new JFXDialogLayout();
    Typed_text.setHeading(new Text("Texto"));
    Typed_text.setBody(new Text(content));
       JFXDialogdialog = newJFXDialog(stackpane,Typed_text,JFXDialog.DialogTransition.TOP);
    dialog.setOverlayClose(true);
    Typed_text.show();
```

Comment: *¿Es pbosible realizar esto?* No sé... has podido hacerlo? Qué tal si lo intentas y miras si puedes hacerlo? Pero no pares al primer problema, vete a la documentación, busca algún método que pueda ayudarte. Si al final no eres capaz de hacerlo, puedes volver e indicarnos ***qué problema tienes***, y seguro que alguien te ayuda :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude lograrlo añadiendo un TextArea y vinculando el ancho y el alto con el del Stackpane